# threejs glft model strange lines

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create something like on this photo
[image]
So, how to remove that strange lines from the model
http://weblife.su/WineBazar/1/
You can see those lines while rorating the model.
What is the problem? I need to use opacity, to get result like on that scrinshot.
At least, can I hide the background for user, but reflectivity and metalness will be on my model?

My threeJs script is here
Thank you for the help!

```html
 <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';

import { OrbitControls } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { RGBELoader } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js';
import { RoughnessMipmapper } from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/utils/RoughnessMipmapper.js';
        var container, controls;
        var camera, scene, renderer;

        init();
        render();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(container);

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.25, 20);
            camera.position.set(-1.8, 0.6, 2.7);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            new RGBELoader()
                .setDataType(THREE.UnsignedByteType)
                .setPath('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/equirectangular/')
                .load('royal_esplanade_1k.hdr', function(texture) {

                    var envMap = pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(texture).texture;

                    scene.background = envMap;
                    scene.environment = envMap;

                    texture.dispose();
                    pmremGenerator.dispose();

                    render();

                    // model

                    // use of RoughnessMipmapper is optional
                    var roughnessMipmapper = new RoughnessMipmapper(renderer);

                                        var loader = new GLTFLoader()
                                        loader.load('http://weblife.su/WineBazar/1/ws_r_2-5.glb', function(gltf) {
                                            gltf.scene.traverse(function(child) {
                    
                                                if (child.isMesh) {
                                                      child.material.color.setHex(0x9ed7f5);
                                                      child.material.emissive.setHex(0x062f61);
                                                      child.material.transparent = true;
                                                      child.material.opacity = 0.5;
                                                      child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                                                      child.material.reflectivity = 0.8;
                                                      child.material.roughness = 0.2;
                                                      child.material.metalness = 0.5;
                                                    child.depthWrite = true;
                    
                                                }
                    
                                            });
                    
                                            scene.add(gltf.scene);
                    
                                            roughnessMipmapper.dispose();
                    
                                            render();
                    
                                        });
                });

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                antialias: true
            });
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
            renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
            renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator(renderer);
            pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();

            controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.addEventListener('change', render); // use if there is no animation loop
            controls.minDistance = 2;
            controls.maxDistance = 32;
            controls.target.set(0, 0, -0.2);
            controls.update();

            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

            render();

        }

        //

        function render() {

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like self-transparency artifacts. You should always set  `depthWrite` to `false` if you encounter such rendering problems. But even this setting might not help to remove all glitches since correctly rendering transparency is very tricky. You would need a special *Order-independent transparency* algorithm like depth-peeling which is not supported by `three.js`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-independent_transparency

Related issue at GitHub: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9977